# Simple log equation

Tags: logarithms

I have a really simple logarithm equation, but I can't for the life of me figure out why it's true. I found it in an algorithms text.

$$3^{\log_4 n} = n^{\log_4 3}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Take $\log_3$ of both sides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take $\log_3$ of both sides, you get $\log_4 n=\log_4 3\log _3 n$.

Do you recognize it now?

Comment: I see. But starting from the left expression, how do you end up on the right?

Comment: Use $\log_3 3^x=x$, $\log_3 n^x=x \log_3 n$, and $  \dfrac{\log_c x}{\log_c b}=\log_b x$